# Send Email in Obiee

Tags: business-intelligence, obiee, oracle-bi

I started using the BI recently and came across a problem.

I have a table created in OBIEE, need to send it to 3 different emails. (Sample Sales)

However necessary that these three e-mails receive different information. For example:

The email1 has access only to the product "TV"
The email2 has access only to the product "Games"
The email3 has access only to the product "Services"

NOTE: These emails are not registered on any user and also will not be registered.

Answer (score 0):

You can create three different reports just by change filter to product is in "TV".. likewise. 
Then you can schedule these three reports to different ids through iBOTs.